# Display X through div of different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, transform

### Problem

How would you go about displaying an **X** through `div`'s of different sizes so it hits all four corners? I want one `solid 1px black` line to go from the **top left** to the **bottom right** of the `div`, and another `solid 1px black` line to go from the **top right** to the **bottom left**.

### Example

If you're not following what I'm talking about, check out my mockup [**here.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phukT.jpg)

### Thoughts

The only solution I can think of for this problem, isn't a solution at all, but just a starting point for thinking about how to implement it. I figure I'd have two `solid 1px black` lines in the center of the div, and then use CSS to `transform: rotate (45deg)` on one line, and `transform: rotate (-45deg)` the other. Of course this isn't a solution that will work with any size div, since the rotation of 45 degrees will only work for a square `<div>`. I have a feeling I'm going to need some *javascript* to calculate the rotation angles. I'd really prefer a pure CSS solution, but I'm not sure CSS would be able to achieve this.

### Code

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/ahedx) is the code I currently have. The **X** is going to be placed through the `.overlay` class.

### Edit

***Edit #1***: If it helps, all of my images are the same width.

***Edit #2***: Is there a way to use HTML Canvas `lineTo()` to reference corners of divs as values?

Comment: I've just been playing with the canvas element. They can be enclosed in a div, put a picture in the div, and the canvas can be in front. Just need to make sure the dimensions of both elements are similar. Still playing, but hopefully will come up with something. Looks very powerful.

Comment: @TimSPQR Are you working on a solution?

Comment: This VERY crude, but I got lines on a canvas and the canvas over a div. I'll try to play some more.http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/uXA6m/

Comment: Update fiddle with picture: http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/uXA6m/2/ - JS will be needed to read the height and width of the picture, then change the canvas line intercept points.

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution for this is a CSS `linear-gradient:`on the `background:`. You create a gradient with two color breaks positioned near 50%. Se the middle break to black, and the rest to transparent. This leaves a thin black line for us to angle however we want. Then you just replicate the gradient it and mirror the angle. Something like the CSS below:

```
.image:hover .overlay {
  //your other exising styles
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
  color-stop(49%,transparent), 
  color-stop(49%,#000000), 
  color-stop(50%,transparent)), 

  -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left bottom, 
  color-stop(49%,transparent), 
  color-stop(49%,#000000), 
  color-stop(50%,transparent));  
}
```

**[EXAMPLE DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/j9XMT/)**

The only remaining issue is that since your images vary in aspect ratio, you can't have your "X" always hit the corners of your image. You'll need to standardize the ratio of your images, or code some javascript that will dynamically do it for each image.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As you said, this only will work for square images. Anything else would require another `<div>` above the `.overlay` class that would need to have the `transform: rotate` property and contain the `linear-gradient:` properties. Thanks for the attempt though. It taught me something new, it just didn't meet the criteria I was looking for. I really need something that works for non-square images automatically.

Comment: Yeah the only thing I can think of then is to have standardized img ratios (if you can do that), and separate overlay classes for each. Or a bit of javascript that will do it for you. But I'll think about it a bit more, there may be a different solution.

Comment: Ya I have a feeling some Javascript will be needed for this answer, and I know just enough to do super basic things. Hopefully someone will be able to write a simple piece of code that can calculate the degrees for `transform: rotate(Xdeg)`. I might be able to have 5 separate classes for five different img ratios like you said. I'm wondering what the best technique would be if I went that route.